# How to make active points of only one dataset with "nearest" mode

Tags: chart.js

I'm displaying 3 datasets using scatter, however, I'd like to show tooltip for only 1 dataset. The issue is that when I'm using the 'nearest' hover mode, it looks for the closest point in all 3 datasets. How do I disable completely the points of the other 2 datasets, so their points don't get observed in the nearest mode? Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43118408/how-to-disable-a-tooltip-for-a-specific-dataset-in-chartjs

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37273824/chart-js-v2-0-tooltip-only-for-one-dataset

Comment: The solutions above are about hiding the tooltip, not about disabling particular dataset points. In the 'nearest' mode the points are still visible for the distance calculation.